# HOW to create circles joined with line,to show progress report in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on a travel app where I have to show the travel plan with drop-down as shown in the image, I don't know how to create these circles joined with dotted line...

If I expand a plan, the respective dotted line expands with it. 
How do I code that in React Native?

Image is taken from bookmundi

[image]

I have used native base, dropdown component, but I need these circles and lines styling too.

Comment: do sure add the answer buddy, if you found any workaround over this.